# Using Angular/Ionic, how do I get my external JS file to show its function on the home.page.html within my app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, external-js

So I have my index.html, home.page.html and js/externaljs file setup, but can't get the externaljs file to return my function specifically to an id="demo" link on my home.page.html so that it won't display on my app. Need help with the coding to target the return value from my function to the id=demo, I've tried most other options on Angular documentation, no luck...

Here's Code from home.page.html file:

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      RANDOM WORD Generator!
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="false">
    <div id="container" class="ion-margin">
    <strong>RANDOM WORD GENERATOR</strong>
 
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-title>RANDOM WORD:</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <ul>
              <li>OR</li>
              <li>AND</li>
              <li>HIS</li>
            </ul>
            <p id="demo"></p>
          <ion-button color="dark" expand="full" (click)="CallExternalJSFileFunction()">Call External JS File Function</ion-button>

            <script src="./myplace/assets/js/swgenfile.js"></script>

          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>

     
    </ion-card>
   
   </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here's swgenfile.js file:

```
var randomWord = [ ]
randomWord[0] = "or";
randomWord[1] = "is";
randomWord[2] = "he";
randomWord[3] = "she";
randomWord[4] = "his";
randomWord[5] = "their";
randomWord[6] = "day";

function randomWord () {
    var randomWordGen = Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomWord.length));
    document.getElementById('pSightWord').innerHTML = randomWord[randomWordGen];
}
```

Again, trying to get above files to communicate and place a random word in the  "placeholder" within my Angular/Ionic app - but its not working obviously. Appreciate any help and input, sorry for the delay - been busy doing everything but learning coding - COVID!

Comment: Could you share some code? I have a hunch you are not using Angular Components properly and it might be due time for a refresh. Either way, with some code that you've written, it shouldn't be too hard to determine what's going on

Comment: You should be able to click "edit" underneath your original question, then add the code there https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow/51145

Comment: function ExternalJSFileFunction(a, b) {
   alert("external function called");
} //example

Comment: Can you check if there is an element in the DOM with the ID you are looking for?  Ionic sometimes uses the ShadowDOM to put things in, so it could be that your placeholder is in there.

Comment: No - nothing there. I was trying to reference the <p id demo portion located in the <ionic card> portion within my code but haven't been successful obvi.